# Grails GORM composition or hasOne?

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I'm a bit confused about the differences between using the static hasOne map and composing objects in domain classes. What are the differences between the two? ie.

```
class DegreeProgram {

String degreeName
Date programOfStudyApproval
static hasOne = [committee:GraduateCommittee]
}
```

versus

```
class DegreeProgram {

String degreeName
Date programOfStudyApproval
GraduateCommittee committee
}
```

where GraduateCommittee is another GORM domain model class.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A hasOne association should be used in the case where you want to store the foreign key reference in child table instead of the parent in a bidirectional one-to-one.

See [this page](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/hasOne.html) for an example:

Comment: I'd skimmed that before but it hadn't really registered. In what cases would I want to store the parent's key in the child as opposed to vice versa?

Comment: @VisionarySoftwareSolutions I guess it's useful in making sure that the child doesn't belong to another parent because it can only hold reference to only one parent.